# OS Command injection

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Is [OS Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Command_Injection) works on winform applications?

Is it major security threat?

If yes, what would be the best posiible solution to secure the application against it?

Any links for the above would be appreciated.

Here is the example code

```
public static void RunNewInstance(ref string pstrUserRole)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string lstrExeName = asm.ManifestModule.Name;
            Process proc = new Process();
            string lstrCurrentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = lstrCurrentDirectory + "\\" + strExeName;

            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = pstrUserRole;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Command_Injection

Comment: avoid shelling out to the OS any client input

Comment: @kenny:Could you give any references on that.I have no clue on that.

Comment: tenfour's answer addresses it. On the code you added. You probably want to cleanse what seems to be the possible user input pstrUserRole. You'll want to make sure that that doesn't allow a OS command to added to it perhaps using '&'. See http://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline

Answer (score 2):

If your winforms app allows user input to execute arbitrary system commands that they would otherwise not be able to perform, then yes it's vulnerable. The solution is to not allow it. Instead of running shell commands, be explicit about what the user is allowed to do. Don't allow the user to do arbitrary stuff.

This is a super-generalized answer, but you gave no specifics about your app so there's no way to know what the best decision is for you.

My guess though is that, because this is a winforms app, the app will likely have the same privileges as the interactive user. In this case, there's nothing your app can do that they can't do by just opening up a command prompt.

Maybe you should give more details about your app, and why you are afraid of this particular vulnerability.

Comment: You mean to say my application shouldn't allow any OS command to execute??.But actually i have been told that <pre>System.Diagnostics.Process.Start</pre> is considered as one of the potential security threat under OS Command injection.<p> i am using that for sending mail through Outlook.

Comment: There's no way to secure your app unless you fully understand the threat. Using `Process.Start` is not a vulnerability by itself. It's how you use it that matters. And you have not given any details about this.

Comment: i have updated the question. The above mentioned code block is considered as one of the security threat.

Comment: @VijayHulmani did you ever come up with a solution for this command injection issue?